# File browser tab displaying in admin overlay

Tags: modal-dialogs

I've got File browser tab displaying in the admin overlay for all authenticated users. WHere is this setting coming from?

Comment: What module did you installed? Media, IMCE, ...?

Comment: IMCE and ckeditor @Nikit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to insert images/upload files](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62650/unable-to-insert-images-upload-files)

Answer (score 1):

There is setting under IMCE configuration to disable this option. Go to admin/config/media/imce click on edit link of Profile. See screenshot below.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using the IMCE file uploader.

You can hide the File browser tab using this module: http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer

However, I think this module simply hides selected tabs from the frontend, and **DOES NOT** disable access or check permissions etc.