# Unable to insert images/upload files

Tags: wysiwyg, files

Since upgrading a module the other day, I am no longer able to upload files to my site.
Has anyone experienced this? If so, how did you fix it?

Actually, I am able to upload a image but not insert it.

Comment: @NikhilM 
Not exactly a duplicate as in the other one there is no mention of being unable to upload insert files.

Comment: It might be an idea to edit this question to make that more obvious, then it'd become a viable candidate for re-opening :) Perhaps add some more details such as what you've tried, or if this problem just appeared and it all worked previously :)